# How to restructure firebase data in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Given the following, how can I restructure my data so that my tag structure looks like this?

```
"tags" : {
  "Tag3": true,
  "Tag4": true
},
```

Currently my code pushes data to firebase like this:

```
"-KXcnfob3Vo3s8bL9WSI" : {
      "name" : "Product 2",
      "description" : "Description of product 2",
      "tags" : [ "Tag 1", "Tag 2", "Tag 3", "etc." ],
      "url" : "websiteURL2.com",

    }
```

I am looking to make it like this:

```
  "-KXcnfob3Vo3s8bL9WSI" : {
    "name" : "Product 2",
    "description" : "Description of product 2",
    "tags" : {
      "Tag3": true,
      "Tag4": true
    },
    "url" : "websiteURL2.com"
  }
```

Here is the code in question:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('products').push({
                name: $scope.product.name,
                description: $scope.product.description,
                url: $scope.product.url,
                dateCreated: Date(),
                tags: $scope.productTags
}



$scope.addToTag = function(tag) {
    if($scope.productTags.indexOf(tag) == -1)
      $scope.productTags.push(tag);

  };
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change you addToTag method like this.

$scope.addToTag = function(tag) {

```
  $scope.productTags[tag]=true;
```

};

make sure $scope.productTags is an object.

```js
var productTags = {};

var addToTag = function(tag) {
    
      productTags[tag]= true;

};


addToTag("Tag1");

console.log(productTags);
```

Comment: Fits like a glove!!  Thanks a ton @Deep !!